# Reformatting a phone number in Laravel using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a function that formats telephone numbers as a user types their phone number in. I also have a blade.php template that has the phone number field as part of the form. How do I get the blade template to invoke my telephone() function from my main.js file?

Contact.blade.php

```
               <div class="field">
                    <label for="name" class="label">Phone Number</label>
                    <div class="control">
                        <input type="text" id="phonenumber" class="input {{$errors->has('phonenumber') ? 'is-danger' : 'is-success'}}"
                               name="phonenumber" placeholder="Enter phone number" value="{{old('phonenumber')}}">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

main.js

```
function telephone(){
    document.getElementById('phonenumber').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
        var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
        e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');
    });
}
```

app.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="{{URL::asset('js/main.js')}}"></script>
    <link href="{{url('/css/style.css')}}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

@include('inc.contact')
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use onKeyDown or onKeyUp on the `phonenumber` input tag and point it to your `telephone()` function

Comment: May you please provide an example? You mean like inline javascript? So something like... onkeydown="telephone()" ....?

Comment: I tried adding the onkeydown on my input tag and refresh the page but the function never gets called? Do you know why?

Comment: Always make sure that your javascript file is being called. Try having console.log on that file.  Then edit your input tag like this.

`<input type="text" id="phonenumber" class="input {{$errors->has('phonenumber') ? 'is-danger' : 'is-success'}}"
                               name="phonenumber" placeholder="Enter phone number" value="{{old('phonenumber')}}" onkeydown="telephone()">`

Comment: This worked, I just tried it in an incognito window so I guess it was the browsers cache. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A server side language (php) can not invoke an action in a client browser; there is a physical boundary that separates the two.

What you are looking for is a an [event in the client browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) that can trigger your function.

main.js

```
function telephone(e){
    var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
    e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');
}
document.getElementById("phonenumber").input = telephone
```

You will also want to make sure your javascript executes after the content of the DOM is available.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="{{url('/css/style.css')}}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    @include('inc.contact')
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{URL::asset('js/main.js')}}"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I put this code in my main.js and refreshed my page but the phone number is still formatted as 5555555555